# How to draw complex signals in simulink

Tags: simulink

I want to draw the output from a QPSK modulator in simulink

but scope block couldn't do that and a message say that the signal is complex and so scope couldn't draw it.

How can I plot such signal and what a block could be used to get the output from QPSK modulator.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate it into real and imaginary parts using the [Complex to Real-Imag](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/complextorealimag.html) block and then you can plot those signals on a scope. If you want them on the same scope, you can either change the scope parameters to have 2 inputs (similar to `subplot` in MATLAB) or multiplex the two signals together with a [Mux](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/mux.html) block (to have two traces on the same set of axes).

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to put a raised cosine transmit filter after the QPSK modulator then plot the output using timescope